# Firebase database Android - mapping datasnapshot child with different structure to java object

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have these data in Firebase database.

[image]

What I want to do is to map this child (list1) on a java object. 
when I want only the children of list1, I'm able to map them on a custom object (f.e. ProductFirebase) using something like this :

```
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    //database.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("list1");


    ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {



            ProductFirebase product = dataSnapshot.getValue(ProductFirebase.class);



        }
```

I don't really know how to map all the lists (list1,list2..etc) since the last two children are structurally different from the siblings.

I was thinking something like

```
Map<String<String, ProductFirebase>> list = (Map<String<String, ProductFirebase>>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

but, of course, last two elements are not a ProductFirebase and it's not working.

There is a way to create an object which matches with the result from dataSnapshot?

One more thing..the number of the nodes with only the value: true is not fixed. There could be more than 2, it depends on the number of the people which share the list.

Thanks in advance

UPDATE :

[image]

This is the general situation. I want to query all the lists where there is the key "8ada6af0-de37-495d-8349-0cd4c215fc87". 
So I'm expecting to receive list1 and list3. And It is!! but now I have my original problem which I described in the first part of the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refactor a bit your database. You should put those nodes, which value are true into a separate node (I call them here *Ids*). Also for the list1, list2, ... nodes you should create a parent node. For exampe:

```
"lists": {
  "list1": {
    "category": "food",
    ...
  },
  "list2": {
    ...
  },
  ...
},
"ids": {
  "8ada6af0-...": true,
  ...
}
```

Now if you create another custom object(let it be Data) which contains:

```
// the inner map is one list object
Map<String, Map<String, ProductFirebase>> mProducts;
Map<String, Ids> mIds;
```

The Ids object should contain:

```
Map<String, Boolean> mIds;
```

Now, with this structure you can get the data, how you already did:

```
Data data = dataSnapshot.getValue(Data.class);
```

I hope that this will solve your problem.

**UPDATE:**

In this case you can store the keys in a separate node and inside it you store the id of the list, which has this key. In your case you'll have:

```
"keys": {
  "8ada6af0-de37-495d-8349-0cd4c215fc87": {
    "list1": true,
    "list3": true
  },
  ...
}
```

First, you make a query for getting the content of "keys/8ada6af0-de37-495d-8349-0cd4c215fc87" node, and after that you make another query to get those lists.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idu9EJPSxiY&index=5&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&t=0s) you can find a good tutorial about how to make queries like this.

Comment: The problem of your solution is that I'm not able to query the structure by grandchild value. list1, list2 and more are children of lists. So, I think it's not possible to query "lists" where ids key = "8ada6af0....". Could I ?

Comment: If you'd like to query by grandchildren, it is possible if you know the path to that child. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild) you can check the orderByChild function.
I don't see the whole picture about your system, so probably the solution above is not the best, but maybe you can create a good structure based on this.